# How to close questions that were already answered on another stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, stackexchange

It looks like that [this Q&A](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2480/210) was answered back in the day on StackOverflow. How to close such questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already answered elsewhere is not a close reason and has no reason to become one in my opinion.

We do have a close reason stating:

> Questions about general programming problems are not on-topic unless
>   they relate to DevOps in some way. You may be able to get help on
>   Stack Overflow instead.

which was discussed here [Add an off-topic close reason for generic programming questions](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/13) and *may* fit the question you linked.

The main reasoning should be 'is this question on topic for our site ?' the fact it is on-topic elsewhere is not specially relevant to close a question here, we can have some overlap with others site on the network.

I think [this answer](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/13) of Shog9 and the comments under it are still applicable to our site at this time.

And a relevant meta.se question on the same subject for the same conclusion: [Is “closer match to another SE” a reason to close an on-topic question as off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303203/287976)